# UE4 with uWebSockets as a third party lib

Tags: linux, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to add uWebSockets lib as a third party lib to UE4 project on Linux. I followed [this](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Linking_Static_Libraries_Using_The_Build_System) tutorial. But I am getting this error message:

> ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: /home/tux/Projects/CarSample/Binaries/Linux/libUE4Editor-Car‌​Sample-1662.so

I think that problem is related to some external dependencies of uWebSockets lib. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the complete compilation error.

Comment: CompilerResultsLog: ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: /home/tux/Projects/CarSample/Binaries/Linux/libUE4Editor-CarSample-1662.so

Comment: "Failed to produce" is the result of a previous error, the log should state what that error is. Can you post that too?

Comment: There is no any other error messages.

Comment: If this is all the compile output, then I cannot help you, sorry.